# Private block chain static time between blocks

Tags: blockchain, ethernet, geth

I'm using geth to create a new private blockchain and I was wondering if there is a way to adjust the difficulty algorithm in order to have a constant time between blocks of around ~5 minutes instead of the standard 13 seconds.
What section of the code should I change?
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/7159/31148

Comment: I understood how to make the difficulty static but what I don't understand is where in the geth code it decides to try and keep the time between blocks around 15 seconds. I would like to create a private network with a different time